# Compile error in full specialisation of function template

Tags: c++, templates

In the following program, I am trying to iterate over a list of types using a meta struct of types.

It compiles and works fine unless I specify `template<>` before the base print template definition.

```
/* example.cpp */
#include <iostream>


template<typename ...>
struct List{};

template<typename T,typename ...Rest>
void print(List<T,Rest ...> *) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    print((List<Rest ...> *)nullptr);
}

// uncommenting the next line creates compilation error
// template<>
void print(List<> *) {
    
}

int main() {

    using L = List<int,double,float>;

    print((L*)nullptr);
}

/* compile and execution
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp
./a.out
i
d
f
*/
```

If I uncomment the `template<>` before the `void print(List<> *)` definition, `g++` and `clang++` both shows error.

```
// clang++ error
error.cpp:15:6: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'print'
void print(List<> *) {
     ^
error.cpp:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
void print(List<T,Rest ...> *) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't understand why this form of full specialization is not working with `template<>` as template header? Am I missing some function template rule here?

Thanks!

**Update:**

The following program compiles and works well, when I added one more mandatory template parameter `U`.

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename ...>
struct List{};

template<typename U,typename T,typename ...Rest>
void print(U* , List<T,Rest ...> *) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    print((int*)nullptr, (List<Rest ...> *)nullptr);
}

// I dont understand, that `T` is missing here, but still compiles
template<typename U>
void print(U *,List<> *) {
    
}

int main() {

    using L = List<int,double,float>;

    print((int*)nullptr,(L*)nullptr);
}
```

I don't understand the cause of `the error` in the first program and the cause of `no error` in the second program.

Comment: Template function specialization is a can of worm. Overloading them is just easier to reason about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary template is:

`template<typename T, typename...Rest> void print(List<T, Rest...> *)`

So one `T` and a pack.

`template<> void print(List<> *)` simply doesn't match.

You would have to have

`template<typename...Ts> void print(List<Ts...> *)` to allow your specialization.

Notice than with fold expression of C++17, it would simply be

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void print(List<Ts...>) {
    ((std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl), ...);
}

int main()
{
    using L = List<int, double, float>;

    print(L{});
}
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the QS with an extra template parameter and it compiles. I don't understand the cause of `the error` in the first program and the cause of `no error` in the second program.

Comment: @Debashish: In your second snippet, you also do overload, and not specialization.

Comment: Ah, I need to read about the differences between template overload and specialization.

Answer (score 1):

Note that default definition of template requires at leas one parameter. So specialization must have at least one parameter.

So alternative solution:

```cpp
template<typename ...>
struct List{};

template<typename T,typename ...Rest>
void print(List<T,Rest ...> *) {
    print((List<T>*)nullptr);
    print((List<Rest ...> *)nullptr);
}

template<typename T>
void print(List<T> *) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GhhWdfoj3

Comment: No it is not, his code is this: https://godbolt.org/z/TYovz99qG

Comment: Working OP's code is [that](https://godbolt.org/z/he7b3zrPn), recursion ends at 0 instead of 1 as you. both use overload.

Answer (score -2):

The reason for your issue is template<> being empty. Consider replacing it with something like:

```
template<typename T>
```

Or something like that. It's totally up to you :)

Comment: Remember I am not going into too much detail to confuse anyone so, doing this should work.

Comment: The problem is that doing this don't work as OP intended. Have you tried compiling the code with your proposed solution?

Comment: Yes. And it compiles just fine.

Comment: `template<typename T> void print(List<> *)` in this case `T` cannot ever be deduced. I'm not sure how you managed to compile it. [Here's the code not compiling](https://godbolt.org/z/zax4q68zx). Substituting the line you mention simply don't work.